# Is it possible to invoke setters in class in Dart?

Tags: dart, oop, getter-setter, encapsulation, setter

Is it possible to invoke setters which declaired with set keyword in class in Dart?

In the script written below, Dart does not recognize the setters:

```
    class Cat {
      String _size = '';
      String _color = '';
      int _age = 0;
    
      Cat(String initialSize, String initialColor, int initialAge) {
         size(initialSize);
         color(initialColor);
         age(initialAge);
      }
    
      // getter and setter fields are started
      String get size {
        return _size;
      }
    
      void set size(String animalSize) {
        _size = animalSize;
      }
    
      String get color {
        return _color;
      }
    
      void set color(String animalColor) {
        _color = animalColor;
      }
    
      int get age {
        return _age;
      }
    
      void set age(int animalAge) {
        _age = animalAge;
      }
      // getter and setter fields are ended
    
    }
```

Error: 'size' isn't a function or method and can't be invoked.

Error: 'color' isn't a function or method and can't be invoked.

Error: 'age' isn't a function or method and can't be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are calling a setter/getter is how you would do an assignment of the field. So your code should be:

```dart
         size = initialSize;
         color = initialColor;
         age = initialAge;
```

This will call the setter of `size`, `color` and `age`.

The point of having getter/setter is to be able to simulate a field but have some logic behind that field other than just direct access to a variable.

**Unrelated to the question:** I don't know if your class is just an example but your current class could be written as the following:

```dart
class Cat {
  String size;
  String color;
  int age;
  
  Cat(this.size, this.color, this.age);
}
```

Of if you want named parameters:

```dart
class Cat {
  String size;
  String color;
  int age;

  Cat({required this.size, required this.color, required this.age});
}
```

It is in general not needed to have getter/setters unless you need to have some logic or want to add restrictions. The great thing about getter/setter in Dart is that they behave like fields so we can just start by having fields and replace the field with a getter and/or setter later if we need to add extra logic.

Comment: I wanted to manage the assignment of values to a class property from a single location, and I wanted to sanitize and validate the assigned value in a single location

Comment: Ok, if that is the case it is fine to have getter and setters as you have done it. I just did not see any validation logic in your example. :)